# tangential acceleration = d|v|/dt leading to negative speed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors

If tangential acceleration is the rate of change of speed, then consider a case where the particle undergoes tangential retardation. For e.g., tangential acceleration $=−t$. Now $d|v|/dt=−t$ where $|v|$ is speed. On integrating, we get $|v|=v_0−t^2/2$. Now if $t> \sqrt{2v_0}$, then $|v|$, which is speed, becomes negative. What stops speed from becoming negative?

Here, tangential acc is the component of acceleration along the velocity vector

Comment: Acceleration can't be equal to $-t$ (assuming $t$ is time)

Comment: You are asking about d|v|/dt in your title and pulling a fast one by asking dv/dt in the bulk. Speed is a useless quantity. Think in terms of velocities. If you absolutely must think in terms of speed then solve for velocity and THEN take the absolute value. This has to do with the absolute value of functions not being analytic.

Comment: But d|v|/dt, which is equal to the tangential acceleration is the rate of change of speed. Although I have used the symbol $v$ in my problem, I have specified that by $v$ I mean speed. I'll edit my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a nonsensical answer, it's because you started with a nonsensical question. In this case, this just tells you that the differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\|\mathbf v\| = -t
$$
simply cannot arise as a consequence of any newtonian equation of motion of the form
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\mathbf v = \mathbf f(\mathbf x,\mathbf v,t).
$$
for unbounded amounts of time. You're guaranteed the latter as part of newtonian mechanics, but there's nothing that guarantees you the ability to set $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\|\mathbf v\| $ to any arbitrary function as you've found. There's no contradiction here other than a faulty premise.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually nothing. But in a real physical system maybe you have constraints, perhaps on the retarding force, perhaps on the 'particle'.

Comment: That and speed is defined to be the absolute value of velocity, so even if the direction of motion reverses, the speed is still positive.

Comment: @ThePhoton ah, a trick question! Yes you are right! I was thinking velocity

Answer (score 1):

Your differential equation means, loosely speaking, that the speed of your particle decreases faster and faster with time. There comes a point when your particle reaches a speed of $0$. At that point it can no longer decrease in speed because it is the slowest in magnitude that it can possible be already. Think about it. Can you slow down a car that is already a rest.